# What is the right granularity for dependencies while doing constructor or setter injection?

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I am trying to define some dependency injection guidelines for myself. What should be the right granularity while defining dependencies for a class that are to be injected either via constructor or setter injection? The class could be a service, repository, etc. Suppose there is a repository class, which looks like following:

```
public class ProductRepository 
{
    //Option-A
    public ProductRepository(DataSource dataSource)
    {
    }

    //Option-B      
    public ProductRepository(SqlSession sqlSession)
    {
    }

    //Option-C
    public ProductRepository(SqlSessionTemplate sqlSessionTemplate)
    {
    }
}
```

The minimum dependency required by the above class is DataSource interface. The repository class internally makes use of the SqlSessionTemplate (implementation of the SqlSession interface). As shown in the code, there are 3 choices for constructor for doing constructor injection. The following is my understanding:

**Option-A (DataSource dependency)**
This is the minimum dependency of the repository class. From consumer point of view this constructor is the right choice but it is not suitable from unit testing point of view because DataSource is internally consumed by the SqlSessionTemplate in the repository implementation.

**Options-B (SqlSession dependency)**
This is the right choice from unit testing point of view but not from the consumer point of view. Additionally the repository implementation is tightly coupled with specific implementation of the interface which is SqlSessionTemplate. Hence it will not work if the consumer passes some different SqlSession interface other than SqlSessionTemplate.

**Options-C (SqlSessionTemplate dependency)**
SqlSessionTemplate being an implementation and not an interface does not seem to be good for unit testing. Also, it is not good for the consumer as instantiating SqlSessionTemplate is more involved as compared to DataSource. Hence discarding this option.

Option-A and Option-B seems to be the available choices. But, there is a trade-off between consumer point of view and unit testing point of view and vice versa.

I am new to dependency injection. I seek advice from the DI experts. What is the right solution (if any)? What would you do in the above situation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> This is the minimum dependency of the repository class.

I think this is the starting point for figuring out the right amount of coupling.  You should be injecting no more or less than is needed to fulfill the requirements.

That's a very general guideline, which is almost the equivalent of "it depends", but it's a good way to start thinking about it.  I don't know enough about DataSource, SqlSession, or SqlSessionTemplate to answer in context.

> The repository class internally makes use of the SqlSessionTemplate
>   (implementation of the SqlSession interface)

Why can't the repository simply use the interface as a dependency?  Does the interface not cover all the public methods of the implementation?  If it doesn't, is the interface even a useful abstraction?

I can't completely piece together what you are trying to do and how the dependencies work, but my best guess is either:

1. You need **both** SqlSession and DataSource injected via the constructor, or
2. You need SqlSession injected via the Repository's constructor, and DataSource injected into the SqlSessionTemplate's constructor

Comment: I have intentionally not attached Java tag with the question. The question is conceptual and it equally applies to .net (if you belong to it). The dilemma being the tradeoff between usability of the API and the unit testing. I have taken repository as example but it could be a framework class with many consumers of it. To provide you more context, SqlSessionTemplate is an implementation of SqlSession but it does not fully abide by the interface contract. In other words, IMO, it violates LSP (Liskov Subst. Principle). SqlSession interface can be thought of light ORM mapper.

Comment: Conceptually DataSource is similar to ADO.net SqlConnection.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about unit testing your repository, but that would typically be rather useless because a repository is your gateway to the database and has a strong coupling with it. Unit testing should be done in isolation, but a repository can only be tested with the database. Thus: an integration test.

If you were able to abstract the database specific logic from the repository (as you seem to be doing) there would be nothing left to test, since the responsibility of the repository is to communicate with the database. And if there still IS a lot left to test, well... in that case your repository classes are probably violating the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), which makes your repositories hard to maintain.

So since you would typically test a repository itself using a database, from a testing perspective it doesn't really matter what you inject, since you will have to construct an repository in such way that it will be able to connect to a database anyway.

Comment: I know that integration testing applies more than unit testing to the repositories. I took repository as an example. It could be a service class, or a low level framework class. You could visualize the situation with a non-repository class.